# Field not displayed with condition

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3

I try to use a condition with th:attr with some value

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'genericForm'+${genericField.field}" th:attr="${genericField.mandatory} ? data-msg=#{mandatory.field}, name=${genericField.field} : name=${genericField.field}"/>
```

Actually, this input is not displayed

error is:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence:
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it render this ? `<input  type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'genericForm'+${genericField.field}" th:attr="${genericField.mandatory} ? (data-msg=#{mandatory.field}, name=${genericField.field}) : name=${genericField.field}"/>`

Comment: no that  change nothing

Comment: I thought it was due to the ternary, you cannot have 2 expressions that are not wrapped within paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

Like this is how I would do it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'genericForm'+${genericField.field}" th:name="${genericField.field}" th:attr="${genericField.mandatory} ? data-msg=#{mandatory.field}"/>
```

You can move name out to th:name since it's in both.

Comment: not working : Attribute name expression evaluated as null or empty: "${genericField.mandatory}? data-msg : ${null}"

Comment: Did you mean to use `data-msg=#{mandatory.field}` in your original question (perhaps you meant `${mandatory.field}`?  I tested my answer, and it works if the data is correct.